# Upgrade TortoiseSVN 1.8 issues

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I upgraded [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to 1.8 from 1.7.12 on Windows XP. After that it asked for upgrading of the SVN format.

I tried upgrading, but it keeps asking and the command produce no error. I tried to checkout a new copy from the server, and it keep asking to upgrade.

I reverted to 1.7.12.

How can I fix this problem?

I don't know what happened, but it seems it started upgrading the repository correctly. Is it maybe a problem with the cache?

Comment: did you upgrade to release 1.8.0 version or to nightly 1.8.99?

Comment: svn, version 1.8.0 (r1490375)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The client side format has been changed.  (As you've noticed)

> Before using Subversion 1.8 with existing working copies, users will
>   be required to run the svn upgrade command to upgrade working copy
>   metadata to the new format. This command may take a while, and for
>   some users, it may be more practical to simply checkout a new working
>   copy.
>   http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html

According to the notes, you've done it correctly.
- Is there more than one svn.exe in your path?  It sounds like an older version was used to upgrade your WC.
- Did you install the command line tools with Tortoise?
- What server version are you using?

Comment: -nope only one svn  
-installed svn with tortoise  
-server 1.6.x  
any way after some rebootS it started to behave correctly, i assume it was a problem with TSVNcache

Comment: I also upgraded to my old Tortoise to latest and getting this message http://i.imgur.com/jQoJ03V.png. I work in a team. If I upgrade to new format will all team members need to upgrade too?

Comment: If you don't upgrade the server, other users will not need to upgrade their svn client.  Further information can be found here http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#compatibility

Answer (score 9):

No Need to delete the .svn folder.

Just right click on the root folder and say 'Upgrade to latest SVN format'.
That will do.

Comment: What if I'm facing this issue on a Mac?

Answer (score 8):

You may need to reboot after upgrading TortoiseSVN, as described here: [SVN Upgrade working copy - TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881366/svn-upgrade-working-copy-tortoisesvn)

That sorted it for me. On reboot, there was a right-click option to Upgrade Working Folder.

Comment: This is the simplest answer and also the only one that worked for me. The key is to reboot after upgrade. Before that, you can't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

1. I suppose, you **did not upgrade** your old (1.7) WCs to 1.8 format
2. Checkouted by 1.8 client Working Copy **must be** in 1.8 format

1.7 WC sample for two different client's versions

- For 1.7 client

  > svn.exe" --version

  `svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)`
  `compiled May 18 2012, 14:19:29`

  > svn.exe ls

`Hello.de.txt
    Hello.en.txt
    Hello.eo.txt
    Hello.fr.txt`

- For 1.8 client (WC if file-level copy of original)

  > svn --version

  `svn, version 1.8.0 (r1490375)`
  `compiled Jun 17 2013, 18:36:16 on x86-microsoft-windows`

  > svn ls

  `svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command`
  `svn: E155036: The working copy at 'Z:\Hello'`
  `is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.0 (r1490375)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem though none of the above answers fixed my issue.

A TortoiseSVN right click does not show the Upgrade as you have already done at a parent level most likely at some point. And prior to the upgrade, there was an .svn in every folder, now there is only one at the top level like git. If you have copied any old code or other code back into a folder at some point, or for some other reason, you will be experiencing the above problem. To solve simply:

1. ensure you are not hiding .svn folders
2. click at the top level and search for .svn
3. delete all .svn folders except for the top level one.
4. right click do an SVN Cleanup 

   Fixed.

Comment: New versions of Tortoise don't give the option of Cleanup. But just doing step 3 did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I has the same issue.

In my case, the problem occurs because an added directory. I just select the option correspondent to the upgrade, and the entire working copy can be commited.