# SVN Upgrade working copy - TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I upgraded my TortoiseSVN client to version 1.8 and made a fresh checkout of a repository.

I made some changes in files and now trying to commit by right clicking on project folder but I'm not able to do it. It shows me 'SVN Upgrade working copy' in context menu, when I try to upgrade it from there, it does not work and kept asking me? I'm not able to commit my changes.

Any idea how to upgrade my local repository? Or it is something to do with the server SVN version?

Comment: You forgot reboot after installing 1.8, your WC have previous version's format. Reboot and re-checkout

Comment: It doesn't tell you to reboot in the installer, but well spotted!

Comment: I think it's best to insert the responses at answer box. To remove them from unanswered questions.

Comment: I'm having this issue, except that the terminal has been rebooted several times since the upgrade. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is just to reboot after installation and it will allow you to commit the files.

Answer (score 38):

You don't have to fully reboot, you just have to kill file explorer (not the IE browser, this is the file explorer) and restart it (in Task Manager kill the explorer process(es) and then go to File->Run and type explorer).  This does close any folders you had open with explorer though.