# How to commit new version using SVN

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

#### Problem (updated)

**1. How can I replace the old version source code with new version?**

I used TortoiseSVN to create a svn folder called `svn://svn.domainname/program/android` and uploaded these source code:

- source code of an Android project
- source code of a supporting library

The local path (in my Mac) of the uploaded files is:

`~/svn_android/`,

and the local path (in my Mac) of my Eclipse workspace is:

`~/dev/android/workspace/`.

After making some changes to my project in `~/dev/android/workspace/`, I want to commit the new version to svn, but it doesn't work by just deleting all files in `~/svn_android/` and copying new version code from `~/dev/android/workspace/` to `~/svn_android/` and committing them.

**Updated:**
There are many newly created files and many modified files, so I don't know what can I do except deleting all of them (except the `~/svn_android/.svn` folder) and copy-and-pasting into the folder with all of the current version source code.

**2. Should I upload the metadata of Eclipse IDE?**

Eclipse is used as IDE for the project. Not sure whether the metadata used in Eclipse has been uploaded in this process. The metadata folder/file is listed here:

- `~/dev/android/workspace/.metadata` (folder)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/.DS_Store` (folder)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.metadata` (folder)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.settings` (folder)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.classpath` (file)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.DS_Store` (file)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.gitignore` (file)
- `~/dev/android/workspace/myproject/.project` (file)

Comment: Do you mean the .project .classpath files? Those generally do not get added to source control.

Comment: You should not be deleting all files in `~/svn_android/`. I don't know about OSX, but in Linux and Windows, there usually will be SVN meta data folder at `~/svn_android/.svn/`. So, keep the `.svn` and delete other files, then copy new files from `~/dev/android/workspace/`. That should work.

Comment: To @shoerat, do you mean copying all of the current version source code or just the newly created files?

Comment: To @Qberticus, then should I manually delete those `.project`, `.classpath` files (see above updated post for the whole list of those meta files)

Comment: Once files are deleted, copy everything (existing and new) you want to commit. As for the new files, you have to first add them: TortoiseSVN GUI > Add.

Comment: After clicking `Add`, error message arrives: "**The working copy at 'Z:\svn_android\mylibrary' is too old(format 29) to work with client version '1.8.0 (r1490375)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.**" The supporting library source code that aforesaid is checked out from svn too.

Comment: The above issue can be solved by methods provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232416/upgrade-tortoisesvn-1-8-issues

Comment: To @shoerat, you can move your comment to answer so that I can mark it as answer, thank you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution to the problem:**

You should not be deleting everything in `~/svn_android/` folder. I don't know about OSX, but in Linux and Windows, there usually will be SVN meta data folder at `~/svn_android/.svn/`. So, keep the `.svn` and delete other files/folders, then copy your working files from ~/dev/android/workspace/ and commit. As for the new files, you have to first add them: **TortoiseSVN GUI > Add**.

**What I personally would do:**

I would keep both local copy of SVN repository and Eclipse project at the same place so that there will be no need for copy/pasting. That's, in Eclipse

```
New Project > Android Project from Existing Code > Root Directory: ~/svn_android/
```

At this point, **leave "Copy projects into workspace" unchecked**.